# Angularjs website not indexing on google

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, seo, search-engine

I developed a large angularjs application with more than 20 pages and add some SEO tags. But it is not functioning well. Most of content of the pages also populate using javascript.
This is how I implemented SEO tags for each pages.

app.js

```
(function() {

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize', 'angular-flexslider']);

// config route
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    var baseUrl = "partials/";

    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        title: 'Title 1',
        metadescription: "Description 1",
        metakeywords: "Keyword 1",
        templateUrl: baseUrl + 'home.html',
        controller: 'homeCtrl'
    })
    .when('/page1', {
        title: 'Title 2',
        metadescription: "Description 2",
        metakeywords: "Keyword 2",
        templateUrl: baseUrl + 'page1.html',
        controller: 'page1Ctrl',
    })

    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
}
]);

app.run(['$location', '$rootScope', function ($location, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) {
        $rootScope.title = current.$$route.title;
        $rootScope.metadescription = current.$$route.metadescription;
        $rootScope.metakeywords = current.$$route.metakeywords;

    });
}]);

}());
```

Meta tags of the html have implemented as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="lennonsApp">
<head>
<base href="/">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title ng-bind="title"></title>
<meta name="description" content="{{metadescription}}">
<meta name="keywords" content="{{metakeywords}}">
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
</head>

<body>
   Content goes here.....
</body>
</html>
```

All the meta tags data bindings are working properly when page loads.But even after one month my website is not searching in search engines. 
This web site is hosted on IIS server. 
My questions:
1).Is this method working on search engines?
2).Do I need to do any other specific configurations for IIS server for angularjs application?
3).Can any one recommend any other method support SEO

Thanks in advance

**Edit**
I tried google.com site:[domain name], none of the seo tags implemented as above is not effected.

**Edit**
Are there any thing to do with IIS server ?

Comment: type into google.com site:[your domain] it will tell you how many pages google has indexed on your site. are you only using the keyword for page? try something like sitegrader to give you a rundown of your seo impact

Comment: Start at: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started

Comment: @atmd I checked my site. Any of meta tags that set by app.js are not showing on the result. Seams my implementation is not supporting for SEO.Yes, I use only keyword and title as my code above.

Comment: @JanithWidarshana I am facing the same problem , Did you get the solution ?

Comment: @ShibinRagh I used prerender.io to solve this problem. if you are using IIS server http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29160320/prerender-io-giving-404-error also will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Search engines tend not to execute JavaScript.

You need to have "real" pages generated server side for the benefit of search engines and users for whom the JS fails for any reason. Then use `pushState` (Angular can do this via its routes) to map Angular pages onto server generated pages.

You can take an [isomorphic](http://isomorphic.net/) approach to the problem and write your JS so it can run server side or client side (which will probably involve running Node.js either instead of IIS or using IIS as a proxy).

Even then, meta keywords are almost always ignored and meta descriptions are usually ignored in favour of analysing the actual content.

Answer (score 1):

SEO implementation on SPAs is not trivial and not all search engine support it currently i think google, and maybe bing are able to crawl SPA's but some work needs to be done for that.
there are several methods you can do this:

```
1 use !# for your angular routes instead of  just #
2 use html5 routes instead of # routes
3 detect crawlers on your server and serve the metadata
4 create snapshots of your site and serve them
```

basically those are most of your options
you can find more details in these articles

http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html
https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/

Comment: I have implement first two by using  this code $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

Comment: they are exclusive, if you use html5 router you don't need to use  # routes. here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Comment: As I know implementation of pushstate is ok in my code.Can you give me any idea where it went wrong? I am bit confused.