# Prerender io giving 404 error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iis, seo, prerender

I created an angulerjs web application and set the SEO tags for each pages like [Angularjs website not indexing on google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28301663/angularjs-website-not-indexing-on-google)

My web application is hosted in IIS server. So I changed my web config file to configure as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="X-Prerender-Token" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <!--# Only proxy the request to Prerender if it's a request for HTML-->
                <rule name="Prerender" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent))(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot" />
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="_escaped_fragment_" ignoreCase="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://service.prerender.io/http://yourwebsite.com/{R:2}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I configure the web config with my own prerender token and logged in to [Prerender.io](http://prerender.io/) and cached my website pages.

When I load http://www.mywebsite.com/?_escaped_fragment_= this link give me "404 - File or directory not found" error now.

Comment: Have you also putted you URL here http://service.prerender.io/http://yourwebsite.com/{R:2} in web config?

Comment: Yes As above, I put it also.

Comment: I replaced Action-> Rewrite to Redirect. Now it seems working.

Comment: You can make answer to your own question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve this problem by changing Action type Rewrite to Redirect as follows.

```
<action type="Redirect" url="http://service.prerender.io/http://yourwebsite.com/{R:2}" />
```

**Edited**

But action type Redirect will effect to social sharing of your web site. So keep it as Rewrite and install Application Request Routing to the IIS server and enable proxy.

This would help to someone :)